# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(5e^{3x})}{\ln(3e^{5x})}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to evaluate the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(5e^{3x})}{\ln(3e^{5x})}$$

So, I did the following:

\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
&\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(5e^{3x})}{\ln(3e^{5x})} \\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{3x\ln(5e)}{5x\ln(3e)} \\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{3\cancel{x}\ln(5e)}{5\cancel{x}\ln(3e)} \\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{3\ln(5e)}{5\ln(3e)}
\end{align}

Now I don't know what to do from here. I know the answer is $\frac{3}{5}$ but how does one get rid of the $\ln$ terms? I thought about breaking them apart but I don't think that will work out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a mistake in your second step: Since $5e^{3x} \ne (5e)^{3x}$, the manipulation involving the logarithm isn't correct. What is true, however, is that

$$\ln(5e^{3x}) = \ln{5} + \ln e^{3x} = 3x + \ln 5$$

Comment: Ahh! I see the reason why. Gotta watch out for those brackets!

Answer (score 3):

$$\ln(ae^{bx}) = \ln(a) {\color{red}{+}} \ln(e^{bx}) = \ln(a) {\color{red}{+}} bx$$ Hence, your expression simplifies to
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\ln(5) + 3x}{\ln(3) + 5x}$$
Trust you can finish from here.

Comment: holy cow, how can you type so fast?

Answer (score 3):

Why not write ${\ln(5 e^{3x}) \over \ln(3  e^{5x}) } = {\ln5 + \ln  e^{3x} \over \ln 3 +   \ln e^{5x} } = {\ln5 + 3x \over \ln 3 +   5x }= { {\ln 5 \over x} + 3 \over {\ln 5 \over 3} + 5}$?

Answer (score 1):

The exponents are only to the $e$, not to the entire $ln$. So you can't do that.

So this simplifies to:

$\frac{\ln(5) + 3x\ln(e)}{\ln(3)+5x\ln(e)}$

$\ln(e)=1$, so we are left with:

$\frac{\ln(5)+3x}{\ln(3)+5x}$

Answer is $\frac{3}{5}$, by our degree rules (same degree on top and bottom, so horizontal asymptote is the ratio).